# "Булка хлеба"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Часто слышу, что люди так говорят. Мне кажется, что это неправильно: хлеб — это хлеб, а булка — это булка. Но, может, я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Булка хлеба - нормальное выражение!) Например, чтобы отличить хлебную булку от булки из песка...)

Comment: Здравствуйте. В Питере никто не говорит "булка хлеба". Мало того, это словосочетание "режет слух" и вызывает раздражение у жителя СПб. У нас говорят про белый хлеб продолговатой формы - батон, булка (напр.: "У нас закончилась булка", про чёрный - хлеб, чёрный хлеб (напр.: "Купи хлеба"). Раньше, в советские годы, когда часто продавался пшеничный хлеб круглой формы, его называли "белый хлеб". Сейчас, наверно, так же.

Comment: А как в таком случае, когда не "Булка хлеба", спросить 2 шт или 5шт хлеба??? С булкой хлеба все просто: купи пять булок хлеба.

Comment: В Петербурге мы говорим «буханка» про черный хлеб в форме кирпича и «батон» про белый в форме батона. «Будьте добры, две буханки хлеба» или «мне, пожалуйста, два батона булки».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут вот какая штука. И "булка", и даже "хлеб" могут означать далеко не одно и то же у разных носителей.

В Питере, например, булка - самостоятельной тип изделия, хлебом не является.
В Москве - один из типов (сортов) белого хлеба.
При этом ни москвич, ни питерец не сможет сказать "булка хлеба", это противоречит их пониманию значения слова.
"Булка хлеба" говорят носители средне-южнорусских говоров, где черный (ржаной) хлеб уже не пекут и не потребляют в количествах, подобных Москве или Питеру, там "булка" - не тип или сорт, а форма, в отличие, скажем, от каравая, калача или батона. "Булка хлеба" в их понимании - штука хлеба.
Кстати, несколько раз убеждался, что многие (не скажу за всех) выходцы из тех краёв плохо понимают привычное для москвича выражение "батон белого (хлеба)" или "буханка черного". Батон, как и буханка, для них понятие самодостаточное, это именно батон, "батон хлеба" - масло масляное. Так что тут, как говорится, один-один.

==============

**Fuchoin Kazuki**, где у вас? И главное - какой он формы? Я и в Голландии нечто подобное едал, только все равно это не ржаной хлеб был, в лучшем случае - смесь.

Настоящего ржаного хлеба, того самого, который издревле противопоставлялся пшеничному, сейчас и в Москве нет. Кое-что могло, конечно, измениться, но ржаным часто называют хлеб из смеси ржаной и пшеничной муки в разных пропорциях, в Нечерноземье и севернее пропорции примерно 50 на 50, южнее - ржаной муки может быть процентов 20, если не меньше.
Так вот, настоящий ржаной хлеб всегда был формовым, "кирпичиком", иначе он просто не пропекался. В Москве и севернее он таковым и остался, хотя, как сказал, состав муки там изменился. Противопоставлять его булке по каким-то дополнительным признаком не было необходимости. Тем более что формового пшеничного хлеба почти и не было.
Иное дело - северные чернозёмы, Урал, Сибирь. Вот там эта "булка хлеба" вполне могло развиться в значении "штука хлеба", поскольку исходное сырье было примерно одинаковым и для формового и для "батонного" хлеба, причин для "московского" или "питерского" понимания "булки" не было, как не было и причин для самого противопоставления ржаного и пшеничного хлеба по составу (как в Питере) или пшеничного - по качеству и форме (как в Москве).

Во всяком случае так было в 80-90 годы, в те года мне довелось поездить по стране.

Comment: Очень даже пекут у нас ржаной хлеб!)))

Comment: Я в тексте ответил. Здесь просто не помещается.

Comment: Вот-вот, у нас на Дальнем Востоке говорят "булка хлеба" про любой сорт хлеба. Вопрос остается: как же правильно с точки зрения литературного языка?

Comment: А какой язык считать "литературным"?
Если московский или питерский, то разумеется, так нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Булка - белый пшеничный хлеб(пищевой продукт, выпекаемый из муки́), обычно круглой или овальной формы.
То есть пшеничный хлеб можно называть булкой.

Скорее всего, ваш вопрос звучит как 
 - правильно ли использовать "булка" вместо "батон" или "буханка".

Да, не запрещено, изначально
bullar — любое съедобное изделие в виде шарика.
Кроме того, у "булки" есть еще много переносных значений.

Answer (score 0):

*Огурец помидора*, *булка хлеба* - это жуть. И в Питере так говорят и в Москве. Булка - это изделие из пшеницы, а хлеб  - изо ржи или пополам с пшеницей. Булка, булочка, есть же такие понятия. Но как *булка* может быть *булкой хлеба*? А так же, как огурец помидора!

Comment: Про "огурец помидора" не слыхивал, а вот с булкой хлева сталкивался. Ничего криминального нет. если вдуматься. просто диалектизм. Писал подробно. В Москве и Питере сейчас почти не осталось коренных москвичей и питерцев. Так что не удивительно. что вы там могли слышать всё. что угодно.

Comment: Огурец помидора - это я для аналогии написала, для меня это звучит также несуразно! ХЛЕБО - БУЛОЧНЫЕ изделия. Хлеб это хлеб, булка это булка. КАКАЯ булка хлеба???????